# css styling the facebook Login Button, best practices

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, iframe

I am using the Facebook [Login Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/login-button) for Single Sign On in my webapp (code below). But I can't figure out how to control the button's styles with css. I see the Facebook plugin inserts an iframe in my page...

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_CA/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=myid";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true"></div>
```

But this doesn't render  :

```
.fb-login-button {
    width: 300px !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    line-height: 30px !important;
    padding: 3px 8px !important;
}
```

JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4SqGn/

Do you know how to control the button styles please ?

Comment: Create the working fiddle for the code, so we can examine your problem and provide solution. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, I added the jsfiddle

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in the fb docu, the `div.fb-login-button` is replaced by an `iframe` by the script you load externally. To style this button yourself, you could just create a button which is styled depending on your wishes and trigger the login mechanism yourself.

For further information, read [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/).

Comment: thanks, I took the quickstart code from your link, but the button they use `<fb:login-button show-faces="true" size="xlarge" max-rows="1" onlogin="Log.info('onlogin_callback')">Facebook</fb:login-button>` is the still the FB "Login button". Can you provide a replacenet code for a customizable button that works with the api ? ...i.e. `<div id="customFbBtn" type="button" class="customFbSignIn" onclick='FB.login(function(response){});'>
      <span class="FBicon"></span>
      <span class="FBbuttonText">Sign in with Facebook</span>
     </div>` doesn't trigger the login

Answer (score 1):

Although quite old, but here is sample code that I am using.

```
<!--HTML-->
<button id="customBtn" (click)='checkLoginState();'>
  <span class="icon"></span>
  <span class="buttonText">Facebook</span>
</button>
<div id='fb-status-login'></div>
```

Below is the CSS(Inspired by google button) you can use. For logo, you can download any 32px*32px png.

```
//CSS
#customBtn {
    display: inline-block;
    background: white;
    color: #444;
    width: 190px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: thin solid #888;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px grey;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  #customBtn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  span.label {
    font-family: serif;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  span.icon {
    background: url('/assets/images/f-normal.png') transparent 5px 50% no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
  }
  span.buttonText {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 42px;
    padding-right: 42px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* Use the Roboto font that is loaded in the <head> */
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  }
```

Inside your component (I am using Angular 4), you can define function like this.

```
public checkLoginState() {
   console.log('checking login status');
    FB.getLoginStatus((response)=> {
      this.statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }
  public statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      console.log('status was already connected. will test api.');
     this.testAPI();
    } else if(response.status ==='not_authorized'){
      console.log('status was not authorised. will call login');

      FB.login((response)=> {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          console.log('status is now connected. will test api.');

          this.testAPI();
        } else {
          console.log('fatal.');

          document.getElementById('fb-status-login').innerHTML = 'some serious shit happened'; 
        }
      });

    } else{
      document.getElementById('fb-status-login').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    }
  }
  public  testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('fb-status-login').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
```

Comment: You meant `click` instead of `(click)` for the HTML attribute name, didn't you?

Comment: As i mentioned, i am using angular so (click) is a valid syntax. But you can use onclick for normal html.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out you can use the (undocumented) colorscheme attribute ('light' or 'dark') with the Login Button, which is for use with other Facebook Social Plugins - Like button etc.

This gives an alternative to the colour of text, and suited my requirements as I had a black background and the default 'light' scheme uses black text, which meant no text in the FB iframe was visible with the default settings.

E.g.

If you need more control over the appearance, you'd be better off creating your own button and use the Javascript SDK to build something custom:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3